MariaDB / MariaBackup : What is the best way to export/migrate a 700GB table to another server, but with only 200GB of free space at the origin?
Origin server:
1 table - InnoDB
-> 700gb - 1.5 billion records
(Free disk space: 200gb)
Destination server is in the same network.
The destination server will have a lot of free space, the origin only has 200gb free.
1 - The table has 1.5 billion records, so querying line by line would not be the best way.
2 - Possibly the only viable way I found at the moment was to copy the IBD file and try to restore it using TABLESPACE, according to the instructions in this link:
https://community.spiceworks.com/t/recover-mysql-database-from-frm-and-ibd-files/1014394
With MariaBackup I would be able to save the file at the source if I had free space.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to send the file via MariaBackup directly to the origin server over the network, right?
Is there any better way to export besides these two mentioned?
Thanks a lot. =)

Maybe pipe the output to ssh then pipe it back in on the other side? But I don't think you can do that using mariabackup because you need to use --prepare first. Maybe rsync?

Destination server is in the same network. Think about INSERT INTO federated_table SELECT * FROM local_table; - see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/federatedx-storage-engine/

Assuming the bandwidth is high, do this on the destination server:
$ mysqldump -u ... -p... -h source_host dbname tablename |
      mysql -u ... -p...                dbname

(If the bandwidth is low, then zipping/unzipping as Kondybas suggests might run up to 3x faster than without zip.)

Also gzip is a preferred compression tool over xz or bzip2 as far as it combines pretty good compression  factor along with a very good speed of compression.

This works if one of the two hosts allows remote connections from other hosts on the same network. Otherwise Kondybas's answer using ssh is the right option.

Bandwidth is good, the servers are in the same rack and will have VLAN between them in the datacenter, 1Gbps dedicated connection between them. So with this bandwidth, this solution without compression will be faster and better and the Kondybas solution?

@CloudStrifes Your mileage may vary depending on the data content and the CPU power available, but for general data the speed difference will not be orders of magnitude.

@CloudStrifes -- same rack & 1Gbps -- skip the compression; it will add too much overhead.  The ssh is for a different reason (as Kondybas points out).

You can stream your dump directly from one host to another with no temporary files on disk at all:
mysqldump -u user -ppass dbname tablename \
   | gzip --stdout                        \
   | ssh sshuser@1.2.3.4 "gunzip --stdout | mysql -u user -ppass dbname"


If zstd is available, that'll probably result in faster compression. Using zstdmt (or zstd -T0) would also allow parallel compression if there's enough CPU cycles to spare. pigz is also another parallel compression alternative that has been used a lot for transferring backups.

@markusjm Unfortunately pigz (and I suspect any other multithreaded compressor) can't compress streams in parallel efficiently. Just because streams are of sequential nature and cannot be read in parts at the same time.

Probably easier to use ssh's -C option to compress and decompress on the fly rather than piping through gzip on both sides.

@Kondybas pigz works with streams pretty well, as long as you feed it with data fast enough. For this very use case, it is better to limit it to (number of available cores)-2 or -1 in order to have enough CPU bandwidth for ssh.

You can, certainly in Linux/UNIX, mount a network filesystem from your target system - say, your DB is on src and you want to copy to tgt. In linux you can use NFS (install NFS server on tgt, NFS client on src) and do:
src $ sudo mount tgt:/exported/directory /your/local/mountpoint

See, for example, Network File System (NFS) - this works on MacOS too, I believe. In windows, you have the map network drive feature, which also works with linux, but is somewhat harder to set up.
And, if you are in the cloud, you can attach a new, larger disk to the source, dump your data, detach it and attach it to the target. That is usually faster than copying over the network.
